# Date formula calculation to skip weekends

Tags: docusignapi

Hi I think this question belongs to the docusign tab and not the API but including there just in case the solution is via API only.  We are creating templates and need a date field that will calculate the date three business days from creation day. today + 3 business days (skip weekends).  Is this possible out of the box?

Comment: Not sure why you guys put this question on hold, it's perfectly clear if you look at DocuSign's API.

Comment: Question reworded, please take off hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible out of the box - you can add days/months/years in your calculations but there's no setting for only considering business days and excluding weekends in the calculation.

You can use the following functions when performing date calculations in your formula tabs:

```
AddDays(d1, n1)
AddMonth(d1, n1)
AddYears(d1, n1)
DateDiff(d1, d2)
Day(d)
Days(d)
```

but as mentioned they include business days as well as weekends.

**However, if you are doing this through the DocuSign API, which means this is coming from code you have written, then you can just perform the calculations in your code (either using a 3rd party library or doing the calcs yourself) and then set the date value based on that.**

For more information on calculated fields including other available functions and operators please see the following guide:

[DocuSign Calculated Fields Guide](http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Quick%20Start%20-%20Using%20the%20Calculated%20Fields%20Feature.pdf)